# Select all from the db

Tags: select, mysqli, bind

I need to print all user in the db but how do I do that? I can't bind baram because there was not thing to bind?

Here is my code:

```
session_start();
    require 'inc/connect.php';

$hey = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
$hey->execute();
$hey->bind_result($all);
$hey->fetch();
$hey->close();

echo $all;
```

Comment: Do you have to bind at all?

Comment: How many columns are there in the *user* table? Provide that many variables to `bind_result`. As you have it, `$all` gets assigned the first column value.

Comment: @CargoMeister $hey->bind_param( what do i type here? );

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles there is seven but how do I bind all of them?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles but I got this messages:Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 7

Comment: You have no need to use `prepare()/execute()` here since you have no variables/parameters to the query. It would be preferable in this case to use `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user");` and `fetch_assoc()` in a loop

Comment: From the manual, looks like you have to provide a var for each column name. So $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3....$col7); It would be nice if you didn't have to do that. But it's been quite a while since I did php with mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table *user* has seven columns, give `bind_result` seven variable names:

```
$hey->bind_result($column_one, $column_two, $column_three, $column_four, $column_five, $column_six, $column_seven);
```

Of course, use variable names that reflect the nature of the data represented.

All together now:

```
session_start();
    require 'inc/connect.php';

$hey = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
$hey->execute();
$hey->bind_result($id, $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $addy, $age);
while ( $hey->fetch() ) {
  echo "$id $fname $lname $email $phone $addy $age<br>";
}
$hey->close();
```

I prefer to be explicit with the SQL and call the columns I want in my results:

```
SELECT id, fname, lname, email, phone, addy, age FROM user
```

...to protect my queries in the case columns are added to the table later.

Comment: And how do I echo them?

Comment: I added an example how to loop over `fetch` and `echo` each record.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 7

Comment: I had a typo in my variable names. Fixed it.

Comment: I've have there was 10, and it work now :D Thanks you, but how do I add a delete box to everone in the list, I know how when I click it delete, but don't know how I make a button to everyone in the list..

Comment: Something like: `echo "$id $fname $lname $email $phone $addy $age<button>Delete</button><br>";` But that's another topic, so ask a separate question.

Comment: Can we write privat or you not have time??

Comment: Like this          $hey = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, rr, house, date, bil FROM user");
$hey->execute();
$hey ->bind_result($id, $username, $email, $rr, $house, $date, $bil);
while ( $hey->fetch() ) {
  echo "$id <br />";
}
$hey->close();

Comment: Type the HTML into your string, like: `echo "<tr><td>$id</td></tr>";`. Try that and if you have problems, ask another question...in order to help keep our stackoverflow nice and tidy.